# Firebase REST API

Tags: ios, swift, rest, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi is there any way to download an image from Firebase Storage using a REST call from iOS or I have to use the iOS SDK?

Comment: One question at a time please.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Storage is built on Google Cloud Storage, so you can use that REST API to access the files. In apps the common way to download files is to use the [download URL that you can get for a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) and use an image-download library. Sample from the linked docs:

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
// Fetch the download URL
starsRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // TODO: download from URL with a REST GET call
  }
}
```